# Um timer para um serviço ler uma tabela no BD

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Preciso fazer com que um serviço leia uma tabela no BD, a cada 5 ou 10 segundos. Não vejo outra forma de fazer isso. Quando nessa tabela uma determinada Flag for alterada, aí o serviço empurra uma mensagem para um App. Não sei se essa é a melhor forma de automatizar meu App, mas é o que tá vindo na cabeça agora e não tenho idéia de como fazer. A lambda que verifica a tabela ok, não sei se o timer ou outra coisa, como fazer. Como implemento esse timer? A idéia seria criar uma Task(async) que lesse a table, mas o problema está no temporizador. Uso Web Api com REST e C#.

Comment: deixa a Task async rodando o tempo todo... `while(true)` e dentro dela coloca o Task.Delay(5000); pra esperar o tempo

Comment: Valeu, @RovannLinhalis, vou fazer esse teste e postar o result.

Comment: Blz, repare no q o Albano falou, isso não deve estar na api e sim no seu servidor

Answer (score 1):

Usar um timer em um uma web API não é uma boa ideia. Eu iria de criar um outro projeto, do tipo windows service, e ai sim usar um timer.

Outra opção, e isso depende do seu banco de dados, seria criar uma trigger que faz a chamada da sua web api no ato da mudança que você espera. Para SQL Server de uma olha [aqui](http://forums.asp.net/t/1904724.aspx?Calling%20a%20Web%20Service%20from%20T%20SQL%20Stored%20Procedure%20using%20MSXML). Resumindo:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Code Snippet
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Agora, sinceramente, eu nunca, jamais, sob hipótese alguma, usaria um `while(true)`. Além de ser deselegante, e ter outras alternativas, a web api espera por uma primeira requisição para ser iniciada. Sendo assim seu `while(true)` só começará a funcionar depois desta requisição, o mesmo se aplica ao timer.